# Power BI Role Filter across tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables in my model;

**Admin Expense to PE**

- PeID
- Email

**Financials**

- ShipToId
- Amount
- AccountId

**Customer**

- ShipToId
- PeId

What I want to do is create a role that will filter the Financials table for specific AccountIds by PeId assigned to specific people.

[Source] <> "Admin Cost Center Postings" 
|| 
Contains('Admin Expense User To PE', 
        'Admin Expense User To PE'[Email], 
        [UserUPN], 
        'Admin Expense User To PE'[PEID], 
        *What goes here to relate from the PeId on the Customer table to Financials Table*
)

Comment: Do you have relationships between the tables? As from the columns would support a filter across the tables that would do this?

Comment: Yes there is a relationship between the Financials and Customer table.  I don't currently have a relationship between the Expense table, but could add one.

Comment: 'Admin Expense to PE'[PeID] to 'Customer'[Peid]. If you set up the relationship, you could filter on the admin table, which would then filter the customer table, then the financial table, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes something like that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could it possible to upload a pbix file to me more concrete ?